# rails3:Unable to get the values of the application constants from the constants defined in the config/application.rb for the authorization plugin

Tags: plugins, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization

Problem :
Unable to get the values of the application constants from the constants defined in the config/application.rb (or environment.rb) for the authorization plugin (in rails3 application)

Description:
I have defined following constants in the application.rb which are required for authorization plugin (used for access control)
AUTHORIZATION_MIXIN = "object roles"
LOGIN_REQUIRED_REDIRECTION = { :controller => '/homes', :action => 'index' }
PERMISSION_DENIED_REDIRECTION = {:controller => '/homes', :action => 'new'}
These constants added in the rails3 application's application.rb are not accessible inside the authorization plugin

Answer (score 1):

**In rails3:**
irb(main):007:0> h = {a:1, b:'2', c:6 }
=> {:a=>1, :b=>"2", :c=>6}
irb(main):008:0> h.keys
=> [:a, :b, :c]
irb(main):009:0> h.keys.include? 'b'
=> false
irb(main):010:0> h.keys.include? :b
=> true

**Solution:**
As authorization plugin checks
Object.constants.include? "LOGIN_REQUIRED_REDIRECTION"
but in rails3 Object.constants returns array of symbols i.e. [:Object, :Module, :Class, :Kernel, :LOGIN_REQUIRED_REDIRECTION, :PERMISSION_DENIED_REDIRECTION, ...] while previously it was returning array of strings
Thus, Object.constants.include? "LOGIN_REQUIRED_REDIRECTION" returns false even if constant is present

To avoid this and to make authorization plugins constants compatible with rails3 we need to add the application constants to config/application.rb file and change the constant in the string to symbol i.e do following changes in the rails-authorization-plugin/lib/authorization.rb

Modify
if not Object.constants.include? "LOGIN_REQUIRED_REDIRECTION"
to
if not Object.constants.include? :LOGIN_REQUIRED_REDIRECTION

Modify
if not Object.constants.include? "PERMISSION_DENIED_REDIRECTION"
to
if not Object.constants.include? :PERMISSION_DENIED_REDIRECTION

Modify
if not Object.constants.include? "STORE_LOCATION_METHOD"
to
if not Object.constants.include? :STORE_LOCATION_METHOD